# Copying files from VB.NET WinForm app to Outlook in Chrome copies only path and not the file

Tags: vb.net, outlook, clipboard, attachment

When I copy file from my vb.net winform app to outlook desktop application as an attachment, it works fine, but when I try to copy the file from winform to outlook opened in chrome, it onlycopies the text of files path and not the file itself. Could there be any restrictions from the browser outlook for copying files? I thought maybe the format of the Clipboard object is the problem since the clipboard object, created from windows desktop includes following formats:

(0)        "Shell IDList Array"        String

(1)        "UsingDefaultDragImage"        String

(2)        "DragImageBits"        String

(3)        "DragContext"        String

(4)        "DragSourceHelperFlags"        String

(5)        "InShellDragLoop"        String

(6)        "FileDrop"        String

(7)        "FileNameW"        String

(8)        "FileName"        String

(9)        "FileContents"        String

(10) "FileGroupDescriptorW"        String

**And the clipboard object created from my app includes these formats:**

(0)        "System.String"        String

(1)        "UnicodeText"        String

(2)        "Text"        String

(3)        "FileGroupDescriptorW"        String

(4)        "FileContents"        String

(5)        "Preferred DropEffect"        Strings

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you get the same picture in a browser with any other web site?

Comment: You mean the same formats?

Comment: I mean any other web site opened in the web browser.

Comment: The drag and drop of the file works in Gmail but not the copy/paste, but I haven't tried other websites.

Comment: Apparently the problem was the incorrect format when creating clipboard object.
I changed 
`(System.Windows.DataFormats.GetDataFormat(DataFormats.Text).Id)`
to
`(System.Windows.DataFormats.GetDataFormat(DataFormats.Bitmap).Id)`.
That was probably why it only pasted the text into mail. Now the drag and drop of the file works fine as an attachment.